# Mounting the windows drives and external usb drives

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed ubuntu on a windows laptop as the second OS.
As I am new user, I created two mounting points in `/mnt/..`  and `/media..`
I tried to remove one, but I couldn't, it's confusing me while working.

How can I remove both mounting points and how to create new mounting points for external usb and windows drives?
My hard disk has three Windows partitions (C,D,E). On E, I took only some space of the available 100GB to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure is that you first unmount any disks that may still be mounted:

`sudo umount /mnt/...`

(that is not a typo, the command is `umount`)

Then the directory /mnt/... is empty and can be removed:

`sudo rmdir /mnt/...`

Then you can make a new mount point elsewhere:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/newmountpoint`

and mount the disk there:

`sudo mount -t auto /dev/[devicename] /mnt/newmountpoint`

If that works, you can edit `/etc/fstab` so the disk will be mounted at the next reboot.

Comment: I succeeded in removing one of the mounting points and continuing with the other.But when i inserted the external usb it is showing in mounting point folder automatically, where as the windows drives are not automatically showing in the list. Please suggest me for automatic detection of windows drives also. Now i am able to access them in mounting point folder after only once i opened them from GUI panel.

Comment: The command `df` will tell you the mount points of each of your currently mounted devices. As I said, if you want to change any mount point, you need to modify `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach how to make Windows partitions auto mounted in Ubuntu.

Run:
`sudo blkid`

You will see UUIDs of your partitions, the next is just an example:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="B23613F43613B875" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="38CE9483CE943AD8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="519CB82E5888AD0F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="00d7d951-2a35-40fd-8e5d-411bb824ff3b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="6044b1d0-208e-4ab3-850d-03a92e1516fc" TYPE="ext4"
```

You shall take a UUID from your output which is corresponding to the partition you are going to automount:

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

For a general-purpose read-write mount, add this line to the end of /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F  /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

but change UUID to yours.

Comment: Happy that it helped!